# How do I intercept a zoom-in event for imageview?

Tags: ios, imageview

I'm displaying an image in an image-view, and I'm trying to overlay labels/text. I'd like to change the overlay when the image-view is zoomed in - what's the best way for me to detect the zoom-in event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to detect zoom events.
If you are not using `UIScrollView` already, you should really use it!